# Prove: $\det(I+A) = 2^{\text{rank}(A)}$ if $A$ is a square idempotent matrix. Find $(I+A)^{-1}$ such that the expression doesn't have inverses.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, jordan-normal-form, idempotents

**To prove:**

$\det(I+A)$ = $2^{\operatorname{rank}(A)}$ if $A \in$ $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $A^{2}=A$.

Find an expression for $(I+A)^{-1}$ such that it does not involve inverses.

Is there any way I could use Jordan Block? I am not sure where I need to start in order to solve it.

Comment: Hint: If $\lambda\in\{0,1\}$ then $\frac1{1+\lambda}=1-\frac\lambda2$. This gives a reasonable guess for $(I+A)^{-1}$, which you can verify by multiplication

Answer (score 3):

Idempotent matrices are diagonalizable to a matrix of the form
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}I_m \\ & 0_{n-m}\end{pmatrix}$$
where $m=\text{rank }A$, $I_m$ is an identity matrix, and $0_m$ is a matrix of all zeroes. (This can be proved using the Jordan normal form and inspection of each block individually.) That is, $A=SBS^{-1}$, so $I+A=SS^{-1}+SBS^{-1}=S(I+B)S^{-1}$ where
$$I+B=\begin{pmatrix}2I_m \\ & I_{n-m}\end{pmatrix}$$
and so $\det(I+A)=\det(S(I+B)S^{-1})=2^m=2^{\text{rank }A}$, as desired.

Hint for the second part: if $A$ was a formal variable you could write down a power series (think of a series for $\frac{1}{1+x}$). But because of $A$'s idempotency, any power series $\sum a_nA^n$ simplifies to one of the form $aI+bA$ (for $a_n,a,b\in\mathbb{C}$). Try using this form to find an inverse to $I+A$.

Comment: Have you actually _done_ that thing with the power series? I don't see how it's going to work. The series that might be $(I+A)^{-1}$ is $I-A+A^2-A^3\dots=I-A(1-1+1-1+1\dots)$, raising the question of what the heck is that...

Comment: Right, I’m not claiming that taking the power series for $1/(1+x)$ will actually give the right answer, just that the fact that power series of $A$, generically, collapse into linear functions of $A$ is a potential motivating starting point for a proper solution.

Comment: I though 1-1+1-1.... gives you 0, but I was wrong, turns out its 1/2. So, its I - A/2. But I am having a hard time understanding how I+B gives $2I_{m}$ on the first block.

Comment: "Evaluating" $1-1+1-1\dots$ can lead to big problems. Seems better just to note that the eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ make it plausible that $(I+A)^{-1}=I-A/2$ and then verify that by multiplying it out.

Comment: If you consider $(I+tA)^{-1}$ for $0<t<1$ you can guess the correct sum should be $1/2$ at $t=1$ and then verify

Comment: @BlackBeard53 Break up $I+B$ into the blocks; $I=\begin{pmatrix}I_m \\ & I_{n-m}\end{pmatrix}$ and so we can just add the $m\times m$ block and the $(n-m)\times(n-m)$ block.

Comment: @CalvinKhor In fact you can _calculate_ it that way, no need to guess: Use the convergent power series to find $R(t)=(I+tA)^{-1}$ for $t<1$ and note that $R$ is continuous at $1$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich indeed; I was trying to avoid a limit argument with matrix valued functions, but we already used an infinite series so nvm that.

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is a polynomial with non-zero constant term and $p(B)=0$ you can use $p$ to find $B^{-1}$. So it seems reasonable to try setting $B=I+A$ and seeing what $p$ we can find. $$0=A^2-A=(B-I)^2-(B-I)=B^2-3B+2I,$$or $$2I=B(3I-B),$$so $$B^{-1}=\frac12(3I-B)=I-\frac12A.$$